# Common refactoring pattern for Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring

Is there a pattern to refactor such a construct into a readable single line?

```
def show_section
  @news = News.all_active
  @news = @news.where(:section => params[:section]) unless params[:section] == "all"
  @news = @news.all
end
```

I use Rails 3 and Ruby 1.9.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@news = News.all_active.where(params[:section] == "all" ? nil : {:section => params[:section]})
```

You can get rid of `@news.all` - in Rails 3 query will be executed when you use the resulting `ActiveRecord::Relation` object (for example when you call `each` or `first` on it). Passing `nil` to `where` method will do nothing.

If `all_active` is a method, you can refactor it into a scope and then call it in a chain.

Great resources on Rails 3 queries:

- [Active Record Queries in Rails 3](http://railscasts.com/episodes/202-active-record-queries-in-rails-3)
- [Advanced Queries in Rails 3](http://railscasts.com/episodes/215-advanced-queries-in-rails-3)
- [Arel README](http://github.com/rails/arel)

Answer (score 1):

You can turn the `where` clause into a method on your News model:

```
class News
  def self.for_section(section)
      where(section == "all" ? nil : {:section => section})
  end
end
```

Then in your controller, you can chain it all together like so:

```
News.for_section(params[:section]).all_active
```

This of course assumes that all_active is also a scope, and not a resultset.